# Python IDLE restart

Tags: python, python-idle

I am trying to run my code inside of IDLE Python i wrote everything is correct but sadly i cannot run.
it restarts without any reason.

```
def calculator():
    operation = input('''
Please Enter one of These:
+ for adding
- for minize
* for multiply
/ for devision
''')

    num1 = int(input('Num 1 : '))
    num2 = int(input('Num 2 : '))

    if operation == '+':
        print(' {} + {} = ' . format(num1 , num2))
        print(num1 + num2)

    elif operation == '-':
        print(' {} - {} = ' . format(num1 , num2))
        print(num1 - num2)

    elif operation == '*':
        print(' {} * {} = ' . format('num1 , num2'))
        print(num1 * num2)

    elif operation == '/':
        print(' {} / {} = ' . format('num1 , num2'))
        print(num1 / num2)

    else:
        print('Error')

    again()

def again():
    calc_again = input('''
Wanna Try Again:
if yes please type Y and if no Please Type N
''')
    if calc_again.upper() == 'Y':
        calculator()

    elif calc_again.upper() == 'N':
        print('Good Bye')
    else:
        again()
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this exactly?

You have defined the `calculator` function but haven't invoked it. If you run the code as you have presented it as a module with IDLE then it will just parse the function into namespace without actually running it.

Try adding `calculator()` to the bottom of your code to actually run the function after it has been declared - does this solve your problem?

Comment: everything is alright but i cannot run my code.
what is the problem unless in IDE i cannot run my code.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't quite understand your problem. How exactly are you trying to run the code you have presented in your question and what do you expect to happen upon execution?

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback,
actually i am trying to run my code for ex :
i have 2 num2 and i need to prompt and put my num1 and num2 .
but sadly my IDLE python restarted without any result.

Comment: can you run my code inside of your IDLE python?
you will understand better what i meant exact.

Comment: I have. As per my first comment, the code as you have submitted it in your question only parses the function definition into the namespace of the interpreter - it does not actually execute it and thus you are not being prompted for input. Try adding `calculator()` to the bottom of your code (outside of the function definition), saving it and then running it again. This will actually run the function after it has been loaded into the namespace at execution time.

Comment: where i have to add calculator() ???
at the end of my all code where else is located:?

can you tell me more prissily?

Comment: At the end of your code, yes. After what you have posted, not indented.

Comment: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to call the calculator() method to start the program (check the last line)..

```
def calculator():
    operation = input('''
Please Enter one of These:
+ for adding
- for minize
* for multiply
/ for devision
''')

    num1 = int(input('Num 1 : '))
    num2 = int(input('Num 2 : '))

    if operation == '+':
        print(' {} + {} = ' . format(num1 , num2))
        print(num1 + num2)

    elif operation == '-':
        print(' {} - {} = ' . format(num1 , num2))
        print(num1 - num2)

    elif operation == '*':
        print(' {} * {} = ' . format('num1 , num2'))
        print(num1 * num2)

    elif operation == '/':
        print(' {} / {} = ' . format('num1 , num2'))
        print(num1 / num2)

    else:
        print('Error')

    again()

def again():
    calc_again = input('''
Wanna Try Again:
if yes please type Y and if no Please Type N
''')
    if calc_again.upper() == 'Y':
        calculator()

    elif calc_again.upper() == 'N':
        print('Good Bye')
    else:
        again()

calculator() #call method
```